# ${aspnet-request-posted-body} with appsetings based configuration

Tags: c#, logging, .net-6.0, nlog, minimal-apis

I was reading whole topics on StackOverflow and NLog's wiki but nothing works for me..

 Maybe I am unable to see something and someone could see it.

I have a minimal API and I would like to log my request from a certain logger.

I found that from v5.1.0 of `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` this is possible via the `${aspnet-request-posted-body}` property, but I am unable to make it work.

In my first try, `Program.cs` looked like this:

```cs
var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("Init main...");

// NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Host.UseNLog();

// and this is what I found
// from https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer
app.UseMiddleware<NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>();
```

and I have an `appsettings.json` file like below:

```json
"NLog": {
    "autoReload": true,
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "internalLogLevel": "Info",
    "internalLogFile": "${basedir}/internal-nlog.txt",
    
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "reqlogfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.txt",
        "layout": "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} | ${logger} | ${message} | Payload: ${aspnet-request-posted-body}"
      },
      "reqlogconsole": {
        "type": "Console",
        "layout": "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} | ${logger} | ${message} | Payload: ${aspnet-request-posted-body}"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "reqlogfile"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "reqlogconsole"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
```

but Payload was empty always.. Anyone knows how to connect the `appsettings` definiton with usage of log request body?

It looks like it is really simple but I am out of ideas.

I simply doesn't remember how many times I tried and what have I done, one thing is constant: I am unable to make it work.

I am also wondering if someone was able to get rid of Microsoft hosting logs.. this also is not listening to me (many config possibilities tried - nothing worked :| ).

Any help will be much appreciate!

Comment: Try changing `"internalLogLevel": "Info"` to `"internalLogLevel": "Debug"`, and check the output in `"internalLogFile"` for possible issues.

Comment: it says `2023-05-16 08:56:24.2271 Debug No available HttpContext, because outside valid request context. Logger: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` not once but for my Program class too. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: `No available HttpContext, because outside valid request context` means that your NLog Target Layout is triggered by logging-statement not related to ongoing HttpRequest. Could you add [${aspnet-request-contentlength}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Response-ContentLength-Layout-Renderer) and [${aspnet-request-has-posted-body}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-Has-Posted-Body-Layout-Renderer) to the Layout just to verify that your active HttpRequest actually includes posted-body-payload ?